# Mining pool, go+redis, many workers connection invoke error accept4: too many open files

Tags: go, redis, ethereum

Trying to run mining pool written in go + redis.

When it is not many worker connected is works fine.
But when it is more (more than 1000) workers trying to communicate with server it is leads to error

Calls in redis_go done in such way.

> tx := r.client.Multi()
>   ms := util.MakeTimestamp() / 1000
>   defer
>   tx.Close()

What can cause problem? As I understand it is problem with max connection? But how can I solve it.

Thank you in advance.

[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Caua.png)

[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQ9YY.png)

ulimit is 65536

update (is such way it doesn't help)

```
func (r *RedisClient) WriteHashRate(login string, id string, hashRate 
int64, expire time.Duration) {
tx := r.client.Multi()
ms := util.MakeTimestamp() / 1000

tx.Exec(func() error {
r.writeHashRate(tx, login, id, hashRate, expire, ms)
return nil
})

tx.Close()
}
```

Comment: classic example use buffered channel: https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#channels

Comment: If the above code snippet is enclosed in for loop, then close `tx.Close()` at the end of the for loop itself, instead of deferring it.

Comment: @nilsocket .  Like this    `func (r *RedisClient) WriteHashRate(login string, id string, hashRate int64, expire time.Duration) {
 tx := r.client.Multi()
 ms := util.MakeTimestamp() / 1000

 tx.Exec(func() error {
  r.writeHashRate(tx, login, id, hashRate, expire, ms)
  return nil
 })

 tx.Close()
}`

Comment: you are calling the same method again and again, It will go into infinite loop, `r.writeHashRate()`

Comment: @nilsocket . Why it will go infinite loop? I'm calling this function once I need to write smth in redis

Comment: you called `r.WriteHashrate(...)`, then once again calling in tx.Exec(), which when executed will once again call tx.Exec(), and so on, you are calling a method which calls itself each and everytime, so it never returns.

Comment: @nilsocket How can I solve it?

Comment: @Natali, how will I known, what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: @nilsocket  I have set of such functions, which are called by miners (workers) to write some data in redis. But in case number of miners more than 1000, server responds with error 'accept4: too many open files'. And I'm looking for decision how to solve it